# Error: Cannot find module 'nativescript-zxing'

Tags: import, module, zxing, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I want to use ZXing in my NativeScript Angular app. I installed the plugin and I´m able to find it in my node_modules folder. But as I try to import the plugin, it says: "Cannot find module 'nativescript-zxing'

I tried reinstalling it, but the issue came back. I can't seem to find any related posts to that topic, as I´m not sure where the problem can be.

This is my import command:

`import { ZXing } from 'nativescript-zxing'`

I hope someone can help me out, or push me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove node_modules folder using `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. add `"nativescript-zxing": "^1.5.8"` in your package.json file
3. npm install
4. Run the `tns run ios` 
   if running on Android, firstly run `rm -rf node_modules/nativescript-zxing/platforms/android` and than `tns run android`

Comment: if i delete all node modules, will my other plugin, that I use, reinstalled later?

Comment: also `"nativescript-zxing": "^1.5.8"` is already inside the package.json

Comment: and I even deleted the `platforms/android` folder beforehand

Comment: you can remove node modules and once you run npm install it will reinstall all plugin again

Comment: I tried your way, but it doesn´t seems like something changed

Comment: Any other ideas?